Using lambda to update the text of a Tkinter Button causes Lambda String to pop up as title
I am currently using tkinter in order to make a poker simulation. I am trying to give each hand(which are represented by buttons which are cards) a text to represent how much money they have. Below is the code for dealing out the hands and where the money is returned.
#This deals the card to each of the players
def dealCard():
   '''Deals the Card to Each of the players'''
   global handCount, cards, cardSuit, cardRank, hand
   for i in range(amountOfPlayers):
       hand = []
       while handCount < 2:
           card = changeCardHand()
           cardSuit = str(card.suit)
           cardRank = str(card.rank)
           cardImage = showCard(cardSuit, cardRank, width= 75, height = 100)
           image_listHand.append(cardImage)
           backImage = Image.open(f"PNG-cards-1.3/card_back_black.png")
           backImage = backImage.resize((75, 100))
           backImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(backImage)
           back_imageList.append(backImage)
           cardButton = tkinter.Button(canvas, image = backImage, text = "0", compound = "bottom", command = lambda index = image_listHand.index(cardImage): [flipImage(index)])
           cardButton.config(text = lambda index = i: [getPlayerMoney(index)])
           button_list.append(cardButton)
           cardButton.place(x = (-25 * amountOfPlayers) + (50*(2*i+1) + 120*(i + 1)) + (handCount + 1)*80, y = (300))
           handCount = handCount + 1
           hand.append(card)
       cards.append(hand)
       handCount = 0 

And here is the code to return the money
def getPlayerMoney(index):
    return str(money[index])

And this is the code which uses an Entry to set the amount of money everyone starts with.
def loadMoney():
    '''Loads the money into each of the players hands'''
    global potValue
    potValue = int(potEntry.get())
    for i in range(amountOfPlayers):
        money.append(potValue)
    potEntry.destroy()

However, instead of the monetary value showing up, each card's text is instead a lambda string as such

How do I fix this issue?

The text option is not called as a function, it's just converted to a string as is. If you want to change the text of the button, you need to do that from the action of whatever changes the amount.

Now text is a lambda function. When you print a lambda function, it will display the lambda string too.
You can remove the lambda function if you don't need it.
cardButton.config(text = [getPlayerMoney(i)])

Or if you need the lambda function
func = lambda index = i: [getPlayerMoney(index)]
cardButton.config(text = func())

